# Convert comma delimited values in a column into rows

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift, denormalized

I would like to convert comma-delimited values into rows in Redshift

For example:

```
store  |location |products
-----------------------------
1      |New York |fruit, drinks, candy...
```

The desired output is:

```
store  |location | products
------------------------------- 
1      |New York | fruit        
1      |New York | drinks         
1      |New York | candy
```

Are there any simple solution that I could split the words based on delimiters and convert into rows? I was looking into this solution but it does not work yet: https://help.looker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024266693-Splitting-Strings-into-Rows-in-the-Absence-of-Table-Generating-Functions

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend not doing this in Redshift.  It should be done before the data is loaded in to the database.  Redshift's capabilities here are very poor.

Comment: Thank you @MatBailie I can also use MySQL if Redshift is not suitable for this task

Comment: If you don't know whether you're using MySQL or Redshift, you already have an issue.  They're intended for ***very*** different purposes.  It's like picking between a tractor or a lorry; they're both vehicles with big engines, but you shouldn't be ploughing fields with a lorry or hauling freight with a tractor...

Comment: *MYSQL is also fine* Precise MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of values, I think you can `split_part()`:

```
select t.store, t.location, split_part(products, ',', n.n) as product
 from t join
      (select 1 as n union all
       select 2 union all
       select 3 union all
       select 4
      ) n
      on split_part(products, ',', n.n) <> '';
```

You can also use:

```
select t.store, t.location, split_part(products, ',', 1) as product
from t 
union all
select t.store, t.location, split_part(products, ',', 2) as product
from t 
where split_part(products, ',', 2) <> ''
union all
select t.store, t.location, split_part(products, ',', 3) as product
from t 
where split_part(products, ',', 3) <> ''
union all
select t.store, t.location, split_part(products, ',', 4) as product
from t 
where split_part(products, ',', 4) <> ''
union all
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a numbers table, as joining against another table is the only way redshift has of turning one row in to many rows (there are no flatten or unnest capabilities).

- For example, a table with 1024 rows with the values 1..1024 in it

Then you can join on that and use `split_part()`

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*,
  numbers.ordinal,
  split_part(your_table.products, ',', numbers.ordinal)  AS product
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  numbers
    ON  numbers.ordinal >= 1
    AND numbers.ordinal <= regexp_count(your_table.products, ',') + 1
```

But...

Redshift is shite at projecting the number of required rows.  It will join the whole 1024 rows, then reject the mis-matching rows.

It performs like a dog.

Because the design assumption is that such processing is always done before loading in to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

> MYSQL is also fine

---

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
> SELECT 1 store, 'New York' location, 'fruit,drinks,candy' products;
>
> SELECT store, location, product
> FROM test
> CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(products, ',', '","'), '"]'),
>                       "$[*]" COLUMNS (product VARCHAR(255) PATH "$")) jsontable
> ```
>
> | store | location | product |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | New York | fruit |
> | 1 | New York | drinks |
> | 1 | New York | candy |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c410a8befafd748beda4030872f34cf2)*

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this will work for up to four comma-separated values.  Note `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`. [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQymchcfzWVg1GENRrLnnF/0)

```sql
SELECT store, location,  
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products, ',', 1)) product
  FROM inventory
 UNION 
SELECT store, location, 
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products, ',', 2), ',', -1))
  FROM inventory
 UNION 
SELECT store, location, 
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products, ',', 3), ',', -1))
  FROM inventory
 UNION 
SELECT store, location, 
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products, ',', 4), ',', -1))
  FROM inventory
```

I'll echo what other people have said.  With respect, comma-separated values is a bad table design.

- It makes for ugly SQL. Being able to read and reason about SQL is very important. Clarity always wins.
- And, the AWS shareholders will love you for it, because you'll spend a *lot* of extra money on redshift.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE temptbl  
(
    store INT,
    location  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    products NVARCHAR(MAX)
)



INSERT temptbl   SELECT 1,  'New York', 'Fruit, drinks, candy'
```

output of created table as u are created

[image: output]

```
select * from temptbl


;WITH tmp(store, location, DataItem, products) AS
(
    SELECT
        store,
        location,
        LEFT(products, CHARINDEX(',', products + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(products, 1, CHARINDEX(',', products + ','), '')
    FROM temptbl
    UNION all

    SELECT
        store  ,
        location,
        LEFT(products, CHARINDEX(',', products + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(products, 1, CHARINDEX(',', products + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        products > ''
)

SELECT
    store,
    location,
    DataItem
FROM tmp
```

You want comma seperated values in Multiple Rows:
output you want  after run above commands:

[image: output]

Hope you find your solution :)))

Comment: I'm suspicious about that running on either MySQL or Redshift

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dff928978249a239bbacbb922eaeceea

Comment: Error of CHARINDEX need to find alias of CHARINDEX

Comment: You've written it for Microsoft SQL Server.  The OP asks for MySQL or Redshift...  Thus must first comment; this is not an answer to the question that was actually asked.